# Different ways to weight probabilities or choose probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

A client has 3 different ads (A, B, C) for their new campaign. Whenever a user comes onto a webpage that hosts our ads, I have to choose which ad to display.

**I choose the ad to display with uniform probability**, so each ad has a ~33% chance to be displayed. The user clicks on the ad depending on which ad is displayed with a probability of x<sub>A</sub>, x<sub>B</sub>, x<sub>C</sub>.

After doing an analysis for each ad, we know that when ad A is displayed, it is clicked on 90% of the time. When ad B is displayed, it is clicked on 70% of the time. When ad C is displayed, it is clicked on 68% of the time.

| Ad | x<sub>i</sub> |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.9 |
| B | 0.7 |
| C | 0.68 |

The question is, what probability distribution should we use to **CHOOSE which ad to display next**, to (1) optimize user clicks, but (2) without losing all data/clicks for the less popular ads, like B and C. So, we can't display ad A 100% of the time to get 90% of probability of getting clicked on.

One method I have thought of is doing a weighting of probabilities. In this case, we would display ad A (0.9)/(0.9+0.7+0.68)=39% of the time.

| Ad | % of the time ad SHOULD be displayed |
| --- | --- |
| A | 39% |
| B | 31% |
| C | 30% |
| **Total** | **100%** |

However, I think there might be a better way to do it, maybe taking into account click probability difference between A and B, etc? The % should add up to 100% for A, B, C.

Comment: This is a [multi-armed bandit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) problem, and actually calculating values is difficult as you have the balance the lower clicks from B and C against the value of testing them, which in turn depends on a pile of assumptions.,  But A is apparently so much better that you should be choosing it either always or at least the large majority of the time

Comment: @Henry In the real world case, the difference between A, B, C might not be as stark. There might also be less/more than three potentially displayed ads. E.g., A, B, C might be 95%, 90%, 85%. In a generalized case where A, B, C could be anything, is there a possible generalized formula?